# Grouping a string into a list of substrings of a certain size

Tags: string, list, haskell, grouping

I have picked up a Haskell book and been writing functions, I am trying to write a function that takes a string and then creates a list of substrings and can choose how many letters you want in each substring.

I've only just started Haskell so not really sure at all where to start.

I have tried using the group function but the whole concept is very confusing to me. and another function called break which apparently breaks however it only creates a tuple of two lists from the original one separated at condition boundary

Comment: That is the first assignment in the book? Perhaps you could start with writing a function signature

Comment: i have seen function signatures such as int->int->bool, but i dont understand how to start off writing a program using that.

Comment: well basically a program *is* a function: it turns input into output. But I would ignore that for now, you can see Haskell first as a query language, and thus implement simply a function. What is not clear about the signatures?

Comment: i have been recommended to use hoogle website for haskell, lets just say we have the signature Int -> Int -> Bool, what signature would i use for the program i am trying to make?

Comment: @JoeKash: I don't follow, what do you mean with "*lets just say we have a signature `Int -> Int -> Bool`*"? Do you know what a signature means?

Comment: Could you explain in a little more detail what your function should do?  Do you want it to take a string like `"hello there!"` and break it into, say, 3-character substrings, like `["hel", "lo ", "the", "re!"]` ?  If you edited your question to add an example, it would help.

Answer (score 0):

The question is a little vague but what it sounds like you want is a function that takes a int and a string and then returns a list of strings the length of the int.

First work out the type of your function.

```
Int -> String -> [String]
```

Prelude has a function called splitAt that will take an int and break a list into a pair. e.g.

```
splitAt 3 "123456789" = ("123", "456789")
```

You can use this recursivley to create the function you want.

```
foo :: Int -> String -> [String]
foo i ""  = []
foo i str = let (x, y) = splitAt i str
            in x : foo i y

foo 3 "123456789" = ["123", "456", "789"]
```

Note that splitAt works on any list and that a string is just a list of characters.

Because of this you can write a more general function that'll work with any list you give it.

```
goo :: Int -> [a] -> [[a]]
goo i []  = []
goo i xs = let (x, y) = splitAt i xs
            in x : goo i y
```

Answer (score 0):

I realize you're looking to write this function yourself. Just for reference, Haskell has a built-in function in the `Data.List.Split` package called `chunksOf` (see the docs [here](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/split-0.2.3.3/docs/Data-List-Split.html#v:chunksOf)). Let's turn to the GHCI repl to see it in practice:

```
> Prelude > import Data.List.Split
> Prelude Data.List.Split > chunksOf 3 "abcdefg"
     ["abc","def","g"]
```